# how to pass structure variables

Tags: global-variables, structure

Am having a set of structure variable in one form, i want to use that structure variable as a global variables. i need to use those structure variable in through out my whole application, how to use structure as global variable??

am using C#..

Comment: In what programming language?

Answer (score 0):

Put your structure variables as static members of a static helper class.

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is a singleton class. Here is an example.

```
public class SingletonClass
{
    #region Singleton instance

    private static SingletonClass _instance;

    public static SingletonClass Instance
    {
        get { return _instance ?? (_instance = new SingletonClass()); }
    }

    #endregion

    #region Contructor

    /// <summary>
    /// Note that your singleton constructor is private.
    /// </summary>
    private SingletonClass()
    {
        // Initialize your class here.
    }

    #endregion

    #region Public properties
    // Place your public properties that you want "Global" in here.

    public enum SomeEnumTypes
    {
        Type1,
        Type2,
        Type3
    }

    public int SomeMeasurements { get; set; }
    public string SomeID { get; set; }

    #endregion
}
```

So when you need this global class, just call on it like so:

```
var currentMeasurements = SingletonClass.Instance.SomeMeasurements;
```

Have fun.